# Generating excel file some fields not shown

Tags: excel, foxpro, visual-foxpro

I was trying to generate an excel file in VS Fox Pro 9 but my problem is that some fields are not shown and I already check the query it is ok becase most of the data shows

Here is my Code as of now

```
    con=SQLCONNECT("odbcname",dbuser,dbpassword)
            q=SQLEXEC(con, sqlstatement)
            SQLDISCONNECT(con)
copy TO folder/r FIELDS AName, DCode, DivCode, Station TYPE xl5
```

the `AName` field does not shows and others are ok, what am i missing something?

`AName` format is `<LastName, FirstName MiddleInitial>`

Any help will be a big help. thanks!

Comment: What type of database are you connecting to there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you verified it looks correct upon browse?